# Is there a way to pass the value attribute of an unsubmitted input field as a parameter of a URL using javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, forms, url, parameter-passing, url-parameters

I am trying to retrieve the value attribute of an unsubmitted input field as parameter to a URL that opens/saves an excel file. The Parameters are supposed to be used to filter the excel file.

I have tried using a for()-loop to save the parameters into an array and then proceed to use the append() method to add them to the end of the url.
Code below shows how I am trying to singularly append each parameter one after the other

```
 var url = new URL("file:database/reports/getCurrentStorageOverview.php?params=excel");

  var query_string = url.search;

  var search_params = new URLSearchParams(query_string);

  search_params.append('params', $("#searchParameter1").val());
  search_params.append('params', $("#searchParameter2").val());
  search_params.append('params', $("#searchParameter3").val());
  search_params.append('params', $("#searchParameter4").val());

  url.search = search_params.toString();

  var new_url = url.toString();

  window.open("database/reports/getCurrentStorageOverview.php?params=excel");

console.log(new_url);
```

The parameters are supposed to be added to the end of the url however the console keeps telling me the value attribute is either undefined/ when i was trying to use an array it was filling the array with 4 "undefined(s)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a different aproach but since i haven't tested your method i can show u what i normally use for this case:

```
const querify = obj => {
return Object.keys(obj)
    .map(key => {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            return querify(obj[key])
        } else {
            return `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(obj[key])}`
        }
    })
    .join('&') }
```

what this does is it takes an object like

```
var filters = { page: 1, length: 10, sortBy: 'id', etc... }
```

and turns it into a query string that looks like "page=1&length=10&sortBy=id" etc so u can use it like this:

```
var url = `database/reports/getCurrentStorageOverview.php?${querify(filters)}`
```

Comment: Ill try it out and let you know

Comment: `const querify = search_params => {`
        `return Object.keys(search_params).map(key => {`

          `if(typeof search_params[key] === 'object'){`
            `return querify(search_params[key])`
          `}else{`

            `return "${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(obj[key])}"`
         ` }`
       `}).join('&')}`
        
        `var url = "database/reports/getCurrentStorageOverview.php?params=excel&${querify(search_params)}"`
        
        `console.log(url);`

       ` window.open(url);`

Comment: im just getting the "encodeURI..." stuck to the end of the url string. Could you help please? Thank you in advance

Comment: are u using alt+96 quotes? thats the only way to make the js work inside the ${} parts. otherwise concat with + symbols like so: `return encodeURIComponente(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[key])`, that should do it!, do the same for the url too if that bothers you, sorry im too used to that syntax heh

Comment: also i tried the method you are using, the URL object has a property called searchParams that's already a URLSearchParams object. have you tried directly appending to it instead of creating a new one and assigning the toString to the search and blabla? the only thing you would have to do is creating the url like the first line, appending each param like you alr know but to the searchParams prop and then calling a toString() on the url to get the final string version of it. sorry i misguided you with my way haha i didnt have time to try out yours yesterday but hope any of them can help you!

Comment: `var url_String = new URL("database/reports/getCurrentStorageOverview.php?params=excel")`  its throwing a typeError saying the url is not valid though it was working fine a few days ago